# i'm having issues opening the console for my App, i'm using firefox

Tags: reactjs, console

I'm currenty working on a register/signup page, i'm in the middle of connecting my server with the front, so i want to do some testing in the console to make sure everything is working fine, however, when opening the console it redirects me to the Debugger tab.

[image: Debugger Tab]

It is not letting me do anything.
How can i get rid of it?

Comment: did you actually look at the displayed page? ... also, look at the error list

Comment: can you clarify what you meant at the displayed page and the error list?
i can't do anything now, it stuck on this page, when i click on the "Deactivate breakpoints" and refresh the page then the "paused on event breakpoint" goes away, but as soon as i try register again it redirects to that page

Comment: displayed page == the screenshot you posted .... start clicking on various parts of the `developer pane` (right side of screenshot) .... start with the red `!`

Answer (score 0):

i  figured it out
i deactivated the breakpoints and then i clicked on the pause break[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjlW0.png)